# access to belongsTo method in same model laravel

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, foreign-keys

I use this model but use this model show below error:

```
Failed calling App\User::jsonSerialize()
```

but remove "$this->customer->name" result is ok.
thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    /**
     * Get the user's customer name.
     *
     * @param  string $value
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCustomerIdAttribute($value)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $value,
            'name' => $this->customer->name
        ];
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'customer_id' => 'array',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the customer record associated with the user.
     */
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: $user = Auth::user();
return $user;

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `$this->customer` is returning `null`, which is causing `$this->customer->name` to cause an error.

When you `json_encode` a Model, or convert it to a string, or otherwise call `toJson` on it, it will call the `jsonSerialize()` method.

At some point, this ends up calling your `getCustomerIdAttribute()` accessor you have defined. Inside this accessor, you have the statement `$this->customer->name`. However, if the current model is not related to a customer record, then `$this->customer` will return `null`, and then `$this->customer->name` will cause an error. When `$this->customer->name` causes an error, it causes `jsonSerialize()` to fail.

In your accessor, just make sure to check if `$this->customer` is valid before attempting to access the `name` attribute:

```
public function getCustomerIdAttribute($value)
{
    return [
        'id' => $value,
        'name' => ($this->customer ? $this->customer->name : null)
    ];
}
```

Comment: show again same error.
I want show customer name in all select of user.

Comment: @HassanDL This should fix the error that you were getting. If you're looking for different help on how to do something, you will need to ask a new question that specifies what you want, with an example of data and output, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: very thanks for answers.
new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327812/show-related-table-columns-in-all-select-of-model-laravel