# show related table columns in all select of model laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship

I want show related table columns (`customers.name`) in all select of model (User) laravel.
I use accessor laravel.

user table:

```
id    name    customer_id
1     hassan  1
```

customer table:

```
id    name
1     customer1
```

now use

```
$user = Auth::user();
return $user;
```

I want show:

```
id: 1,
name: "hassan",
customer_id: {
    id: 1,
    name: "customer1"
}
```

but show this error:

Failed calling App\User::jsonSerialize()

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use EntrustUserTrait;

    /**
     * Get the user's customer name.
     *
     * @param  string $value
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCustomerIdAttribute($value)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $value,
            'name' => $this->customer->name
        ];
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'customer_id' => 'array',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the customer record associated with the user.
     */
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: explain clearly.what do you want to get?

Comment: edit answer, please show again. thanks.

Comment: if you have good solution ( except accessor laravel ),
please explain.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to get customer name from users table based on customer_id in users.

In User.php model

```
public function customer(){
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::class,'id','customer_id');
}
```

Then,

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->customer;
```

Comment: I want use ::all().

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a known issue (https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/issues/879).

I would suggest, after getting your ::all() result, you loop through it and call $user->customer.

```
foreach($result as $user) $user->customer;
```

Comment: I use this code before but I want find a good solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the $casts property. There is no way an integer can be converted to an array *directly from the database*, as the casts property is immediately used when selecting attributes from the database.

Also, there is no need for the getCustomerIdAttribute method, as the customer will be automatically be converted to a fictive attribute called 'customer'.

In short: just defining the customer relationship is enough. It should return the requested output except for it being called 'customer' instead of 'customer_id'.

Answer (score 0):

I find answer.

```
public function getCustomerNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['customer_name'] = ($this->customer ? $this->customer->name : null);
}

/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = [
    'customer_name',
];
```